# Why is the output of this subtraction wrong?

Tags: javascript

Why is the output of this subtraction wrong?

```js
var a = 1753.10
var b = 87.66
var c = a - b

console.log(c);
```

The given output is `1665.4399...` but the calculator given output is `1665.44`

Comment: Oh man, its just rounding. Both outputs are right.

Comment: Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery. I edited it as such.

Comment: I need Not Rounded Value - Need Absolute Value

Comment: You can use `toFixed` method, To round 2 decimal points use `Number(1665.4399999999998.toFixed(2))`